# If an UNION doesn't contain the same column I can't use it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I read this online:

Each query in a `UNION` must contain the same columns, expressions, or aggregate functions, and they must be listed in the same order.

If this saying if I have a query for example

```
SELECT   TOP (1) WITH TIES employee_id, SUM(stars) AS 'total'
FROM     Table_A
GROUP BY employee_id
ORDER BY 'total' DESC
```

I can't use `UNION` to get from a different `table_B` the name of the employee that `TABLE_A` doesn't have. 
`Table_B` share the `employee_id` is just call differently `emp_id` and I would like to output the name of the employee which only `TABLE_B` has `emp_namefirst`, `emp_namelast`.

Comment: in an union u can use different columns (even different tables) as long as the first select and the second select have the same number of columns in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that is saying is that the queries in a union must produce result sets with the same schema.  It says absolutely nothing about the original source tables.  As long as your subqueries produce the same number of columns with the same data types and in the same order then you're fine.  Obviously the point of a union is to get a single result set so there can only be one set of columns so each subquery's result set must match that.

From what you've described, union is completely irrelevant to you.  A union adds rows.  You want to add columns.  You want a join, not a union.

Comment: thank you, it seems the more i read about join and union the more i get confuse. I need to stop thinking too hard about it.

Comment: Like I said, a union adds rows while a join adds columns.  A union takes the result of a second query and adds it onto the bottom of the result of the first query while a join takes columns from two sources and puts them into a single row.  If you want records from two different tables (or other source) to create a single row in the output then you want a join.

Answer (score 1):

Just to recap what was originally asked:

> I can't use UNION to get from a different table_B the name of the employee that TABLE_A doesnt have. Table_B share the employee_id is just call differently (emp_id) and I would like to output the name of the employee which only TABLE_B has (emp_namefirst, emp_namelast).

Your example looks like you need a table `JOIN` to connect two tables with different data sources to connect your `Table_A` aggregations with the employee name information from `Table_B`.

> `Table_B` share the `employee_id` is just call differently (`emp_id`)

Further, you want to see lined up with your results:

> The name of the employee which only `TABLE_B` has (`emp_namefirst`, `emp_namelast`).

**Comments:**  I found additional discussion on [TOP(N) Queries](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/01/select-top-with-ties-in-sql-server.html) that might help you with your query.  I also agree with the other comment contributors that it isn't a `UNION` that you are looking for.

You have two different relational tables that are connected by a common ID or KEY value (employee_id and emp_id).  Records in each table with the same values for these two columns should be connected as parts of the same record.  That indicates a potential `JOIN` relationship.

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES b.employee_id, b.emp_namefirst, b.emp_namelast, 
       agg_sub_query.total
  FROM TABLE_B b,
       (SELECT a.emp_id, SUM(a.stars) as total
          FROM TABLE_A a
         GROUP BY a.emp_id ) agg_sub_query
 WHERE b.employee_id = agg_sub_query.emp_id  
 ORDER BY agg_sub_query.total DESC
```

An alternative approach is to remove the inner sub query and join the tables immediately:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES b.employee_id, b.emp_namefirst, b.emp_namelast, 
       SUM(a.stars) as total
  FROM TABLE_B b, TABLE_A a
 WHERE b.employee_id = a.emp_id
 GROUP BY b.employee_id  
 ORDER BY SUM(a.stars) DESC
```

The first thing you will notice as you see more examples of the various styles of `SQL JOIN` syntax, you will notice another style that differs from my example (above), which is the `ANSI JOIN SYNTAX`.  Both are valid for most database systems.  Each has a different advantage and really should depend more on what you and others supporting your code find easier to read and interpret.

**SQL JOINS**:  Additional References on How to Use Them

- [ANSI Style Join Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)
- [More Explanations for SQL Joins](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)